# Dictionary with Word Popularity?

Tags: algorithm, security, dictionary

It's clear there are a lot of text dictionaries out there, but they don't have a weighting for each word.

I'd like an english dictionary text file that somehow had a weight for each word that was that words popularity (really by any definition of popularity would be fine -- instances on google, instances in books, etc.).

Anyone know of anything out there?

Comment: The search term you need is [**corpus**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus)

Answer (score 2):

[google n-grams](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) will fit what you want. It's a (huge) list of n-grams with their number of occurances, and it is publicly available.

```
uni-gram - single words
bi-grams - all pairs of 'word1 word2'
...
```

Comment: Amit thanks that's awesome, but that's super verbose for my needs (I don't need each year).  Short of stripping those huge files myself, any other simpler list out there with just dictionary of <word> => <metric_of_popularity>?